# How can I get the commit metadata for the buffer region in Git-Log-View mode?

Tags: git, emacs, elisp

I'd like to write a set of elisp functions to manipulate commits identified by the currently selected region when viewing a git log in Git-Log-View mode of vc.el. A common subcomponent of these functions would need to be a function that would obtain the commit metadata for the list of commits selected by the region in the Git-Log-View buffer, but I have no idea how to write such a routine. I was hoping that vc.el provided such a mechanism directly, but from what I can see via apropos it doesn't.

I've poked around in vc.el and vc-git.el to try to get some idea of how vc.el works, but it is a fairly complex bit of elisp and I'm by no means an elisp expert. It seems reasonable to me though that vc.el/vc-git.el has the commit metadata available somewhere, since in Git-Log-View mode you can do things like select a region and ask for a changeset diff over that region, or expand a given commit to see the detailed commit info, and I just want to build some similar functionality.

Any thoughts on how to do this? I suppose I could just directly get the currently selected text and parse the abbreviated log format myself, but that seems like a huge amount of work that I'd like to avoid if vc-mode can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vc-git` and other backends don't really keep the whole bulk of metadata anywhere. For most operations, the backend calls the respective command to get the required data.

For example, `Git-Log-View` is a prettified output of `git log [-- filename]`. The summary you see when expanding a commit was already present in the command output, just hidden, so it's easier for the user to scan. To show the changeset over a region, `log-view-diff-changeset` looks which commits correspond to the region bounds, and delegates to `vc-diff-internal`, which eventually calls `git diff FROM TO`.

So you'll get the hashes of each commit in the region, then call some git command (`git show`?) with `vc-git-command`, `vc-git--call` or maybe `vc-git--run-command-string` for each of them and parse the results. Maybe just call `git log` for all of them at once if you manage to make it include all the relevant data.

Comment: Thanks much. I think maybe I can at least simplify what I need to do by re-using log-view-current-tag, which I think I might not have found for a while without your pointing me to the relevant functions.